# How to construct homomorphisms as modules?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I've seen a lot of work on homomorphisms of modules, but is it possible to construct a homomorphism as a module itself? For example, how would you define a specific module structure on a set of homomorphisms, for example, a dual space.

Comment: You should be more specific. Any such hom set has a Z-module structure.

Answer (score 1):

$Hom_R(M,N)$ the set of $R$-module homomorphisms from $M$ to $N$ is an $R$-module.  Prove that.

Comment: Only if $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Yes, $R$ needs to be commutative for the above to work.

Comment: ok. however there are also old people on this site, and these won't see my comment otherwise!

Comment: More generally, if $M$ is some $(R,S)$-bimodule and $N$ is some $(R,T)$-bimodule, then $\hom_R(M,N)$ is a $(S,T)$-bimodule (via $(s f t)(m) = f(m s) t$). Besides, we have the usual adjunction formula $\hom_{S,T}(B,\hom_R(M,N)) \cong \hom_{R,T}(M \otimes_S B,N)$ for $(S,T)$-bimodules $B$.